# Does Task.ConfigureAwait(false) on the last method line affect anything?

Tags: wpf, multithreading, async-await, task-parallel-library, task

I understand that calling ConfigureAwait(false) on a task that is being awaited will sometimes have a performance benefit, as it prevents an unnecessary return to the original SynchroniZationContext.

For example:

```
async Task Something()
{
   // Let's say I'm on the UI context
   //...
   await AnotherTask.ConfigureAwait(false);

   // Code here is no longer running on the UI context.
   // It runs in a thread pool synchronization context (i.e. null).
}
```

My question is this: If the task call is on the last line of the method, and we skip the ConfigureAwait(false), is the compiler smart enough to prevent an unnecessary return to the original context?

```
async Task Something()
{
   // Let's say I'm on the UI context
   //...
   await AnotherTask; // Dropped -> .ConfigureAwait(false);        
}
```

Will there be a **performance penalty** or **potential deadlock** possible here, even though there is nothing in the method after the await call?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> is the compiler smart enough to prevent an unnecessary return to the original context?

Not yet.

> Will there be a performance penalty or potential deadlock possible here, even though there is nothing in the method after the await call?

Yes.

Comment: Thanks Stephen for your clear and to-the-point response. I also just bought your Concurrency in C# Cookbook from Amazon to sharpen my knowledge :)

Comment: May I invite you to look at this question as well :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41908593/is-there-any-way-to-see-the-full-stack-trace-across-multiple-threads?noredirect=1#comment70998869_41908593